# Data position in file

Tags: c++, windows, file

At first I loaded all my variables to memory at application start.
Over time, the number of variables became so huge that I don't want to do that anymore.
Instead I am retrieving them only when they are needed (using a mapped file, but that is another story).

At first I write the variables to a file.
(this is repeated many times...)

```
vector<udtAudioInfo>::iterator it = nAudioInfos.Content().begin();
for (;it != nAudioInfos.Content().end(); ++it)

    //I think here I should store the position where the data will begin in the file
    //I still need to add code for that...

    //now write the variables 
    fwrite(&it->UnitID,sizeof(int),1,outfile);
    fwrite(&it->FloatVal,sizeof(double),1,outfile);

    //I think here I should store the length of the data written
    //I still need to add code for that...
 }
```

But now that I need to load the variables dynamically, I need to keep track of where they are actually stored.

My question would be: How can I find out the current write position? I think and hope that I could use this to keep track over where the data actually resides in the file.

Comment: Have you looked into `ftell`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `ftell()` as you are reading or writing the variables.

For example, in your example code above, you could find the position at the start of each iteration with:

```
 long fpos = ftell( outfile );
```

When you are ready to return to that position, you can use `fseek()`. (Below, SEEK_SET makes the position relative to the beginning of the file.)

```
 fseek ( infile, position, SEEK_SET );
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read all variables at once, maybe using a struct:

```
struct AppData
{
    udtAudioInfo audioInfos[1024];
    int infoCount;

    ... // other data
};
```

And then load/save it via:

```
AppData appData;
fread(appData, 1, sizeof(AppData), infile);
...
fwrite(appData, 1, sizeof(AppData), outfile);
```

Actually, this is going to be much faster than multiple read/write operations.